# Bar and moving average plot

Tags: plot, line, stata, moving-average

I´m trying to make this kind of chart of Covid cases and moving averages using Stata. I tried using `graph bar` but it plots densities. I want to make a plot against time with this kind of vertical lines. This is the plot I´m trying to make:

[image]

Data for any country:

[https://ourworldindata.org/covid-cases?country=IND~USA~GBR~CAN~DEU~FRA](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-cases?country=IND%7EUSA%7EGBR%7ECAN%7EDEU%7EFRA)

Comment: `graph bar` defaults to showing means. It doesn't offer a handle to show densities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create this kind of plot you can easily use the `twoway` command. This command allows you to combine an arbitrary number of different graphs. You are looking to combine a bar graph with a line graph. For example, the new cases plot for Great Britain can be created as follows:

```
import owid-covid-data.csv

keep if iso_code=="GBR"
keep date new_cases
gen date2 = date(date, "YMD")
format date2 %td

tsset date2 // Set data to time series format 
tssmooth ma ma7=new_cases, window(6 1 0) // create the 7 day moving-average

twoway (bar  new_cases  date2) (line  ma7 date2)
```

[image]

Comment: For reproducibility, mention the `scheme` you are using.

Comment: Thanks Nick and cgx, really helpful, `set scheme lean2` looks good to me